# XML Object Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Im trying to post data to a web application that only accepts XML. I have created the objects in c# (as below) and am using the `XmlSerializer` to serialize the object to XML but cannot work out how to structure the objects in order to get the resulting XML that the receiving application requires:

**The REQUIRED resulting XML**

```
<recipients>
    <gsm messageId="clientmsgID1">number1</gsm>
    <gsm messageId="clientmsgID2">number2</gsm>
    <gsm messageId="clientmsgID3">number3</gsm>
    <gsm messageId="clientmsgID4">number4</gsm>
</recipients>
```

**My objects**

```
public class recipients
{
    public List<gsm> gsm{ get; set; }

    public recipients()
    {
        gsm = new List<gsm>();
    }
}

public class gsm
{
    [XmlText]
    public string number { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string messageId{ get; set; }
}
```

**My resulting XML**

```
<recipients>
    <gsm>
        <gsm messageId="clientmsgID1">number1</gsm>
    </gsm>
</recipients>
```

Comment: how is your xml file structured now?

Comment: I will update the question now with my current results.

Answer (score 3):

use xsd.exe and try passing the xml file shown above. This will create a xsd file, use this xsd to create a cs class, and then use that cs class in your application which would create the same XMl on Serializing
e.g

C:>xsd gsm.xml where gsm.xml will have the xml tags you have pasted above

and then 
C:>xsd gsm.xsd /c to generate cs class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public partial class recipients {
  private recipientsGsm[] itemsField;

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("gsm", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
  public recipientsGsm[] Items {
    get { return this.itemsField; }
    set { this.itemsField = value; }
  }
}


public partial class recipientsGsm {
  private string messageIdField;
  private string valueField;

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
  public string messageId {
    get { return this.messageIdField; }
    set { this.messageIdField = value; }
  }

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
  public string Value {
    get { return this.valueField; }
    set { this.valueField = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new here. some part of code block (class name declaration line)is rendered as simple text

Answer (score 2):

you only need to add

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("gsm", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
```

at class recipients

```
public class recipients
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("gsm", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
    public List<gsm> gsm{ get; set; }

    public recipients()
    {
        gsm = new List<gsm>();
    }
}
```

and it should work

Comment: I didn't get a chance to test this before I'd managed to fix my solution (as posted above) - this is a nice easy way to fix it in future so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your property **gsm** with an attribute **[XmlElement("gsm")]**

Full listing of classes:

```
public class recipients
{
    [XmlElement("gsm")]
    public List<gsm> gsm { get; set; }

    public recipients()
    {
        gsm = new List<gsm>();
    }
}

public class gsm
{
    [XmlText]
    public string number { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string messageId { get; set; }
}
```

Sample code:

```
var a = new recipients();
a.gsm.Add(new gsm() { messageId = "1", number = "aaa" });
a.gsm.Add(new gsm() { messageId = "2", number = "bbb" });
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(recipients));
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, a, ns);
```

Output from my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipients>
  <gsm messageId="1">aaa</gsm>
  <gsm messageId="2">bbb</gsm>
</recipients>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I managed to resolve the issue myself before trying some of the other suggestions and thought I should post the fix here anyway.

I made the `recipients` implement `List<gsm>`. Done :)

```
public class recipients: List<gsm>
{
    private List<gsm> gsms{ get; set; }

    public recipients()
    {
        gsms = new List<gsm>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<gsm> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return gsms.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class gsm
{
    [XmlText]
    public string number { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string messageId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is really dangerous, it won't behave as a `List<gsm>` unless you overload all the methods. Ex `recipients.Add(new gsm())` will add an element not enumerated by `recipients.GetEnumerator()`.